# How to request mobile version of the site that is using @media rules?

Tags: node.js, mobile, media-queries

I'm interested in getting content of mobile version of the site that is using @ media queries detection, while I'm on desktop.

I know I can use different user-agent but it's working on page that use agent to detect mobile users. but is there any way to set a page width and page height in a request, so server that use @media rules will answer with a mobile version of the site?

Answer (score 1):

`@media` rules are for the browser and not for the server. The browser is the one that should parse the html/css and display the relevant content/style bases on them.

If the browser support @media query, and you have a query for max width = 360px, the browser should use the style from this block only if the width of the current window is less than 360px.

Comment: Yea, I know what do you mean but how (from server side) to make browser to get [@]media rule for max width = 360px if user resolution is 1280x800px? User can simply make it's window smaller, but I have no idea what to do when my server want to download mobile wersion of the page that is using @media for user that has his desktop set as 1280x800px.

Comment: Well - basically the page is exactly the same. The differences are only what the browser will display (it is not something the server will send differently). The exact same structure will be display differently, based on the `@media` queries.